# AJAX. POST and retrieve data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm starting a cordova/phonegap app.

I want all DB connections to sync with server (I have a running SQLite DB locally and want to sync with SQL in server). To try and sync I have this code:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
 method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

 // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
 // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
 var form = document.createElement("form");
 form.setAttribute("method", method);
 form.setAttribute("action", path);

 for(var key in params) {
     if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
         hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

         form.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
 }

 document.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
}
```

Ok, but as I'm new to AJAX I did something wrong. What I want is to show in span the result of transaction, but it redirects me to another page where it shows the result.

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I changed into AJAX, this is my new function:

```
var formData = {name:"ravi",age:"31"}; //Array 

  $.ajax({
      url : "http://........",
      type: "POST",
      data : formData,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
          console.log("Data:");
          console.log(data);
          console.log("textStatus:");
          console.log(textStatus);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
  });
```

But I get this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: What you did wrong is not using AJAX. That's just a regular old form submission. Take a look at jQuery's [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll change my function to AJAX and see what happens

Comment: Just did it. When tryed I got this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`